# What POST serialization issues does PayPal PHP IPN example refer to?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

PayPal's sample code for a PHP IPN listener has this comment/code at the top:

```
// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
```

Can someone explain what serialization issues this comment refers to? While I'm ok doing it this way, I would feel more comfortable knowing why it should be done this way.

Comment: Not sure what this means in context, but `$_POST` doesn't always contain the same thing as `php://input`. For example: `key=val1&key=val2` will result in only one entry for `key` in the `$_POST` array. And also, `php://input` is read-only whereas `$_POST` is not.

Comment: Looking at a test page I put up, sure enough the `$raw_post_array` would contain both `key` entries, in an indexed array.
However, the rest of the sample code ends up parsing the raw data into an array. Comparing the two arrays, their custom
`$myPost` array is identical to `$_POST`. ie: keeping the last declared `$key = 'val2'`.

Comment: Why in the *world* do they do that instead of just using [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str)?  Could they be referring to something odd that it does?  It uses the same code that generates `$_GET` and `$_POST` after all...

Comment: Sample codes will be worst, ever!

Comment: Some of the code which I found at paypal is redundant. You could just use `if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())` as well as `curl_setopt_array()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't tell you paypals motivations, but I can guess: php likes to change the keys of incoming variables from an http request.

For example, the name `a.b [` would show up as `$_POST['a_b__']`. php will replace spaces, dots, and open brackets with underscores:
source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Also, php will parse well formed matching brackets in variable names into nested arrays. eg, `arr[a][b]` would show up as `$_POST['arr']['a']['b']`.
http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Also, php behaves all kinds of crazy and buggy when brackets aren't well formed:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48597

Also, `magic_quotes_gpc` used to have its talons into every php installation, changing the names of variables in certain cases too. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Also, php has the `arg_seperator.input` setting, and some people like to set this to `&amp;` instead of just `&`. Paypal cannot know which you prefer, and would obviously always use `&` when crafting a url and/or post body to request, causing your php engine to parse the params wrong.
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.input

Also, despite being bad practice, it's not too uncommon in php for code/libraries to automatically modify the request inputs such as `$_POST`, eg to xss "sanitize" them or other such cross cutting concerns. $_POST is a writable/modifiable variable, whereas php://input is read only, so it's guaranteed not to be mucked with by libraries.

By parsing the input manually, you avoid all those potential issues. This decision seems like good engineering on their part.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks for the references, too!

Comment: Good answer. Makes sense now.

Comment: Thank you. Had me confused too.